# Fullcalendar onclick timeslot events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

With the [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) jQuery plugin, is it possible to display an alert with a time slot (e.g. "hello you clicked on 4/10/2014-1-2 pm) when clicking on any timeslot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's useful.

You can trigger that alert on `select`:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    alert('you have clicked on this slot');
},
```

Here is a basic example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6wE8v/575/